# Custom icons for taskbar without titles on Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, icons, tabbar

Hello everyone) I am new to C # and Xamarin.forms. Now I'm making a mobile application on xamarin.forms and I have a question about adding my own icons to the taskbar: I don't know what I did wrong, but I wrote links to icons for TabBar without errors, but the icons are not displayed. I threw the icons themselves into the project folder, android and ios (and I also don’t know how to remove the headers so that there are only icons) ...

This is how I want to implement it:
[! [enter image description here] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66ZcP.png)] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66ZcP.png)

This is how my tab bar is written:

```
<TabBar>
    <ShellContent
                  Icon = "icon_user.png"
                  ContentTemplate = "{DataTemplate views: PersonalAreaPage}" />
    <ShellContent
                  Icon = "icon_srqr.png"
                  ContentTemplate = "{DataTemplate views: HomePage}" />
    <ShellContent
                  Icon = "icon_settings.png"
                  ContentTemplate = "{DataTemplate views: SettingsPage}" />

</TabBar>
```

Here's what happened in the end ...:
[! [enter image description here] [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqiJJ.jpg)] [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqiJJ.jpg)
What exactly is wrong with me? Maybe I entered the wrong path or something ...
Please help me add my icons and make them centered without titles.

Comment: did you read the docs on image and place the image files in the correct location for each platform?

Comment: No, I haven't read it. I did it myself ... I compressed the icons, made them the same size and dropped them into a folder  "drawable" for each operating system

Comment: okay, i'm reading now....About "drawable" yes?

Comment: there is an entire section on [Local Images](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#local-images) and where they should be placed for each platform

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll read it now

Comment: YEah, its work's, thanks))))  By the way, do you know how to remove the tab headers under the icons?

Comment: by default they use the Title property of their child pages

Comment: That is, there is no way to remove it?
Or is it possible?
I just would like without them, only large icons in the tab bar.

Pardon my dumb brain

Comment: Remove the Title property of the child pages.  Or you could try setting the Title property of the ShellContent items to an empty string